# PHP : List Files of Type in Directory and Link to them

Tags: php

I've got the code

```
$directory = "C:/My file path";
$phpfiles = glob($directory . "*.html");

foreach($phpfiles as $phpfiles)
{
echo $phpfiles;
}
```

But how would I change it so that it doesn't just list the files, but actually links to them?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First of all, don't use same variable names at foreach(). You can link to files, like this.

```
foreach($phpfiles as $phpfile)
{
echo "<a href=$phpfile>".basename($phpfile)."</a>";
}
```

`$phpfile` containing full path of file (for example : /home/eray/Desktop/test.html)

`basename()` is returning just file name from path . `basename($phpfile)`'s output is `test.html` . If you want to print just `test` (without `.html` extension) , you can use this : `basename($phpfile, ".html")` Thanks, @aSeptik.

Comment: `basename($phpfile, '.html');`

Comment: Yes you can use it, too. If you don't want to print file's extension (i mean `.html`)

Comment: my files has special characters like "ą" "ć" "ł", "ó" in name and it's not listed properly on the page, how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the links are accessible via a web server you'll need a different root path for web access than you have on your computer. Also, your foreach is wrong. The second variable needs to be singular (well, at least different than the first). So assuming your web server sees the file path as a valid site path:

```
$rootPath = "/MyFilePath";
foreach ($phpfiles as $phpfile)
{
    echo "<a href=\"$rootPath/$phpfile\">$phpfile</a>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$files = glob("*.html");
echo '<ul>'.implode('', array_map('sprintf', array_fill(0, count($files), '<li><a href="%s">%s</a></li>'), $files, $files)).'</ul>';
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is ok "eray"**

> $phpfile containing full path of file (for example :
>   /home/eray/Desktop/test.html) basename() is returning just file name
>   from path . basename($phpfile)'s output is test.html . If you want to
>   print just test (without .html extension) , you can use this :
>   basename($phpfile, ".html") Thanks, @aSeptik.

how to remove. php extension and in the link.

exaple:
**http//example.com/dir1/file**.php **

> (with out .php on end).

---

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer the question of how to link to them?

Comment: This question is not how to do it

Comment: The question is **how would I change it so that it doesn't just list the files, but actually links to them?**

Comment: This is code echo "<a href=$phpfile>".basename($phpfile)."</a>";

Comment: This is code echo "<a href=$phpfile>".basename($phpfile, ".html")."</a>" is a good but part code a href=$phpfile>, shows link with php extension. I need some help in order to withhold the extension from the link.